Astro loop doesn't add spacing when splitting a title
Im trying to build a Title component that takes in a text prop that gets split using the text.split(" ") JS method. This array of words is then looped over and rendered in wathever heading tag that gets passed to the component. The issue is when the loop renders the title there is no spacing in between words. But when i manualy put the divs inside the tag the spacing is there. Am I missing something or is this intended behavior?
The components in use:
<Title
    Tag="h2"
    text="This is an example"
/>

And the component code with the loop:
---
interface Props {
    Tag: string
    text: string
    class?: string
    line?: boolean
    highlight?: number[]
}

const { Tag, text, class: className, line, highlight } = Astro.props

const splitTitle = text.split(" ")
---

<Tag class:list={["c-title", className]}>
    {splitTitle.map((word, index) => <div>{word}</div>)}
</Tag>

<style is:global lang="scss">
    .c-title {
        --title-color: var(--scheme-contrast);

        color: var(--title-color);

        div {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
</style>

renders to this:
Thisisanexample

And the component code without the loop:
---
interface Props {
    Tag: string
    text: string
    class?: string
    line?: boolean
    highlight?: number[]
}

const { Tag, text, class: className, line, highlight } = Astro.props

const splitTitle = text.split(" ")
---

<Tag class:list={["c-title", className]}>
    <div>This</div>
    <div>is</div>
    <div>an</div>
    <div>example</div>
</Tag>

<style is:global lang="scss">
    .c-title {
        --title-color: var(--scheme-contrast);

        color: var(--title-color);

        div {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
</style>

renders the intended behavior:
This is an example

The rendered DOM for both methods is the exact same so I don't get why it would behave differently.

It's not "the exact same". In the second one there is whitespace between the divs.

Yep indeed. Dev tools just doesn't show it without editing the HTML :)

<Tag class:list={["c-new-title", className]}>
    {
        splitTitle.map((word, index) => (
            <>
                <div>{word}</div>
            </>
        ))
    }
</Tag>

adding a fragment fixes the issue. The divs were getting rendered stuck to each other.
